# Joins a table with multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Table_1 (
   id int,
   tablename varchar(max),
   createdDate datetime
)
```

Now let's suppose there are 20 rows with `id` 1-20. Hence `tablename` contains 20 different names (name1, name2,..., name20). Now these names have their own tables with `n` rows in the same database.

Format of tablenames:

```
name1(
   slno int,
   data varchar(100),
   createdby int,
   processeddate datetime
)

name2(
   slno int,
   data varchar(100),
   createdby int,
   processeddate datetime
)
...
name20(
   slno int,
   data varchar(100),
   createdby int,
   processeddate datetime
)
```

Now I created

```
temp_table(
   ID int,
   tablename varchar(max),
   createdby int,
   createdDate datetime
)
```

which will store ID, tablename, createddate and createdby from the respective `tablename`

Help me to develop a query to fill `temp_table`.

Comment: Your design is horrible -- you are in big trouble.

Comment: Thanks Octoshape to design my query in perfect way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to every one who given me such your important time.
After long patience i resolved this issue.

For this issue SQL dynamic query is required.
How, i am going to explain...

```
While ((Select Count(*) From Table_1) > 0 )
Begin
Declare @ID int = (Select top 1 ID From Table_1),
        @tableName varchar(max) = (select TableName From Table_1 where id = @id),
        @CreatedDate DateTime = (select CreatedDate From Table_1 Where id = @id),
        @Createdby int,
        @Data int,
        @query1 varhcar(max)
        set @query1 = '
                       Select @Createdby =  (select top 1 createdby From +'@tableName'+ ),
                              @Data = (Select Count(data) From +'@tableName'+ )
                      '
        declare @query2 varchar(100)
        set @query2 = '@Createdby output,@Data output'
        exec sp_executesql @query1,
                           @query2,
                           @Createdby = @Createdby output,
                           @Data = @Data output
        insert into Temp_table
        Values(@ID,@TableName,@Createdby,@createddate)
        Delete From Table_1 where id = @id
end
Select * from Temp_table
```

Comment: Guys please vote me because i am facing answer ban issue with my stackoverflow account !!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE HOW TO MAKE YOUR CRAZY DATA LOOK GOOD**

*read my comments below first*

You can make your data look like well designed table with the query below (and then use this to migrate to a clean design):

```
SELECT 1 as dataid, 'name1' as name, s1no, data, createdby, processdate FROM name1
  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as dataid, 'name2' as name, s1no, data, createdby, processdate FROM name2
  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 as dataid, 'name3' as name, s1no, data, createdby, processdate FROM name3
  UNION ALL 
-- etc
  UNION ALL 
SELECT 20 as dataid, 'name20' as name, s1no, data, createdby, processdate FROM name20
```

---

This probably should be a comment, but there is just not room to express in the comment area.

Your data model is flawed.  There should not be 1-N tables.  There should be one column that represents this information -- this is a common mistake when people first start working with relational data.

Here is how I would set it it up:

**Tables table:**

```
dataid int,        -- this is the same as the 1-20 
name varchar(max), -- you probably don't need this since you have an ID
slno int,
data varchar(100),
createdby int,
processeddate datetime
```

So with this table you can select on `dataid = x` to get the same results as selecting a specific table in your design.  I'd suggest adding an index to this column (since every select will use it.)

Now we have a better design.  I'm still not clear on what query you were asking to be designed.

For example to see a list of what "tables" exist when they were created and how many rows they have you would simply do this:

```
 SELECT dataid as tableid, 
        min(name) as name,
        min(processdate) as createdate, 
        max(processdate) as lastaccess,
        count(*) as numberrecords
 FROM tablestable
 GROUP BY dataid
```

Comment: +1 Kudos for your effort. And sorry for the rant in the comments above :D

Comment: @Hogan  sorry hogan but this is not useful !!

Comment: @MindHunter Sorry but I can't help unless you tell me why?  Do you already have tables as you describe?  I can give you a query to turn them into this table.

Comment: Yeah these types of tables exists